# Issue with glReadPixels from GL driver / Chrome & Atom both crash when link is clicked in Atom

Tags: google-chrome, url, atom-editor, glreadpixels, ubuntu-19.04

I'm just getting up and running with a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04. Running into some unusual behavior with Atom.io and Chrome. Whenever I click a link in Atom, both Atom and Chrome crash out. When they restart, the link is open on Chrome. I've searched for similar issues and have found none.
So, this is what I know. The syslog shows this:

```
Jun 27 09:37:41 GLITCH dbus-daemon[979]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.2265' (uid=1000 pid=14413 comm="/usr/share/atom/atom --executed-from=/home/dkm --p" label="unconfined")
Jun 27 09:37:41 GLITCH systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 27 09:37:42 GLITCH dbus-daemon[979]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 27 09:37:42 GLITCH systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 27 09:38:12 GLITCH systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jun 27 09:38:52 GLITCH dbus-daemon[979]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.2267' (uid=1000 pid=8884 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome protocol://domainName[dot]TLD/path    " label="unconfined")
Jun 27 09:38:52 GLITCH systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Jun 27 09:38:54 GLITCH gnome-shell[3089]: The required ID of 2039326 does not refer to an existing actor; this usually implies that the pick() of an actor is not correctly implemented or that there is an error in the glReadPixels() implementation of the GL driver
```

Note: I had to replace actual URL with "protocol://domainName[dot]TLD/path" so it's postable. The URL doesn't matter anyway. It happens with any link.

From the error output, I'm guessing that this has something to do with glReadPixels() method from the GL driver. I don't know what exactly an "actor" is or what the "pick()" of an actor is.

I included the entire log relating to the incident because I'm not sure what may or may not be helpful.

I'm not familiar enough with such things to really know how to go about solving this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[::EDIT::]
So, this may have been when chrome and atom came back up - I'm not sure. But this might also be helpful - might not.

```
Jun 27 09:39:25 GLITCH systemd-resolved[864]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Jun 27 09:40:12 GLITCH kernel: [125248.641505] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlx60a44cec5643 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:98:fe:94:61:c7:01:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.103 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=31378 PROTO=2
Jun 27 09:39:25 GLITCH systemd-resolved[864]: message repeated 5 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
```

Comment: “Clicking on a link” implies that you're using a third-party package of some kind. It would be helpful to know what it is. In general, some more context and maybe a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.